# Connect Two Points in QGIS By Tracing a Line Layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, line, lines-to-points, draw

I have Multiple Points in two separate layer and I want to Join them by a line creating new line layer (shapefile), But I want it to trace an existing Infrastructure that is points connected by Lines.
From the Picture I want to join Green dots with red dots (They have unique IDs BY which we can define which ones to connect) by tracing the infrastructure (blue lines connecting Black boxes).

In a nutshell I want a plugin that works like Join by lines (Hub line) algorithm, But traces the existing Line Infrastructure.

(Join by lines (hub lines)
This algorithm creates hub and spoke diagrams by connecting lines from points on the Spoke layer to matching points in the Hub layer.
Determination of which hub goes with each point is based on a match between the Hub ID field on the hub points and the Spoke ID field on the spoke points.
If input layers are not point layers, a point on the surface of the geometries will be taken as the connecting location.
Optionally, geodesic lines can be created, which represent the shortest path on the surface of an ellipsoid. When geodesic mode is used, it is possible to split the created lines at the antimeridian (±180 degrees longitude), which can improve rendering of the lines. Additionally, the distance between vertices can be specified. A smaller distance results in a denser, more accurate line.)

[image]

Comment: You would expect the shortest part to be used, or is each of the red points supposed to have a unique connection using the offshoots of the line?

Comment: Each of the red point is supposed to have separate lines.